# stochastic integral with respect to a Brownian motion of a simple process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

Given a simple process $H_u:=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} h_i \mathbb{1}_{(t_i, t_{i+1}]} (u)$, where $h_i$ is bounded and $\mathcal{F}_{t_i}$ measurable, I have defined its stochastic integral with respect to a Brownian motion in the following way :$ \int_0^t H_u du:=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} h_i (B_{t_{i+1}\wedge t}-B_{t_i \wedge t})$.

Moreover, given $0 \leq s \leq t$, I have $\int_s^t H_u d B_u := \int_0^t H_u d B_u-\int_0^s H_u d B_u$.

The problem is the following : given $X\ \mathcal{F}_s$ measurable and bounded, how can I prove that $\int_s^t X H_u d B_u = X \int_s^t H_u d B_u$ ? I am told to interpret the left hand side as $\int_s^t X H_u \mathbb{1}_{(s,t]} (u) d B_u$, but I actually do not know how to use this fact. Intuitively, I would say that since $X$ is $\mathcal{F}_s$ measurable, it will be also $\mathcal{F}_u$ measurable for any $u>s$ and therefore in that integral $X$ is kind of a constant, but I am not so sure about how to say it formally. Thank you very much for any help you can provide.

Comment: Maybe this might help (I'm not a guru, so take it with a pinch of salt)

If you plug $H_u \rightarrow X1_{(s,t]}(u)H_u$ in your definition of $\int_s^t H_udB_u :=\int_0^t H_udB_u -\int_0^s H_udB_u$, then the second integral on the r.h.s vanishes. You can then use your definition of the stochastic integral in the 3rd line with the same substitution $X$ should factor out of the sum